# Why did Naru not want Lin to know he bent a spoon?

Tags: ghost-hunt

In the Ghost Hunt anime, in the "The After-School Hexer" story (episodes 7-10), Naru shows that he can bend a spoon using psychokinesis, but asks Mai not to tell Lin he did so.

It is revealed at the end of the first (and only) season that

> Naru has tremendous psychic powers, that are too much for a human being to control, therefore he must not use them. Lin looks after Naru and is the one who has told him not to use his powers.

But later in the same story arc, it is revealed that

> Naru used a trick to bend the spoon. There was no psychic power involved.

So why would he need to hide this from Lin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ghost hunt is good mystery story instead of horror story.

Warn: I wrote follow part based on novel which anime version doesn't covered and contains spoiler.

> Naru has psychic power.

The scene that naru describe the trick is mislead.

The story is:

1. Naru cuts the spoon, Mai see it.
2. Mai talk about (1) to lin, monk and other member.
3. Lin is angry and mock asked how to do it to naru.
4. Naru bents the spoon by using trick.
5. Naru apologize to lin.

> The point is the difference between 1 and 4.
>  Naru cuts the spoon at 1. but in 4, Naru just bets.
>  The trick which naru describe in 4, naru can't cut the spoon.

The real story is different:

> 1. Naru cuts spoon by psychic power.
>  2. Mai talk naru **cuts**.
>  3. Lin is angry because naru uses psychic power.
>  4. Naru try to cheat monk using trick, because he'd like to hide his psychic power.
>  5. Naru success to convince monk and mai.
>  But lin know that trick doesn't work for cut which mai talked in 2, and naru know he can't convince lin by this story. Then he apologize to lin about use psychic power.